# Java Script Contradicts with Each Other

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Using this Java Script to do horizontal/vertical scrolling in gridview.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ExtgridviewScroll();
    });

    function ExtgridviewScroll() {
        gridView1 = $('#GridView2').gridviewScroll({
            width: 950,
            height: 500,

            railcolor: "#F0F0F0",
            barcolor: "#CDCDCD",
            barhovercolor: "#606060",
            bgcolor: "#F0F0F0",
            freezesize: 1,
            arrowsize: 30,
            varrowtopimg: "Images/arrowvt.png",
            varrowbottomimg: "Images/arrowvb.png",
            harrowleftimg: "Images/arrowhl.png",
            harrowrightimg: "Images/arrowhr.png",
            headerrowcount: 1,
            railsize: 16,
            barsize: 15
        });
    }
</script>
```

But when I use the below Java script in the same web page then the gridview is loosing the Horizontal/Vertical Scrollbar which is produced by the above JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modalLoader");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loadingLoader");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
    $('form').live("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();
    });

</script>
```

Why both are contradicting with each other.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? Please be aware that [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is depricated from jQuery 1.7 and removed since 1.9 (latest release is 3.3).

Comment: No errors.  First JS is simply not working.